# What happens when I reinstance a ObservableCollection

Tags: wpf, listview, observablecollection

I have a `ObservableCollection` property and also this property

```
 public ListCollectionView ListView
 {
    get
    {
      return (ListCollectionView)(CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(List));
    }
 }
```

With List being the ObservableCollection

In WPF I have a ListView Control bound to the ListView property.

So as I understand it if I change the ObservableCollection in code it should be reflected in the View.

But what if I just do `List = new ObservableCollection<SomeType>(someElements)`

The list in the View doesn't update at all. Is there anyway to get it to refresh in code behind if I'm doing it MVVM ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add another change notification for the view:

```
public ObservableCollection<...> List
{
    get {...}
    set
    {
        if (list != value)
        {
            list = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("List");
            OnPropertyChanged("ListView");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think my brain was malfunctioning or something yesterday. Such a obvious solution. I also noticed that ListCollectionView has a refresh function, not sure how it works.

Answer (score 1):

You should raise the `PropertyChanged` event for `ListView`.

Answer (score 1):

In that case you would have to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and fire the `PropertyChanged` event for the `ListView` property to force the framework to update the binding. Generally, however, you want to avoid re-instancing, and always update the same `ObservableCollection`.

Answer (score 1):

you need to raise a property changed event for the List itself, either make the property a DependancyProperty or use INotifyPropertyChanged

Answer (score 1):

The control binds to the `ListView` property and listens to the `IPropertyChanged` event so that it can update itself if the underlying view changes. However, it cannot magically determine that the view has changed when you changed the underlying collection.

A direct solution would be to trigger `PropertyChanged` for the `ListView` property just after you change the value of `List`.